# PHP: Referencing Global Functions in Namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I came across a weird issue that I cannot explain with namespaces. The function `array()` does not seem to allow a global reference using `\array()` in namespaces. Is this expected functionality or some kind of inconsistency in PHP?

The error that is returned is:
`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ARRAY, expecting T_STRING in php shell code on line 2`

The follow piece of code replicates the error that is shown:

```
<?php
namespace Testing;

final class Test {
    private $properties = \array(
        "test" => "testing",
        "weird_functionality" => "test"
    );
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array()` is not a function, it's basically a language primitive ("language construct"). As you see, it even has its own parser token `T_ARRAY`.

So yes, that's expected, since it's not affected by namespacing to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

`array()` is not a function it is a language construct and cannot being namespaced.

Use this (without the `\`):

```
<?php
namespace Testing;

final class Test {
    private $properties = array(
        "test" => "testing",
        "weird_functionality" => "test"
    );
}
```